# Multi Language Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, localization, internationalization

I'm building a site for a client that requires several languages. They have all the text required for all the languages. But what's the best (correct) way to implement this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not how to design your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from your question that your client has different pages/posts already translated to several languages. If you are using wordpress I would recommend to use a wordpress translation plugin such as WPML (this is the only one I tested and It has always given me good results but it´s a premium plugin). 
In case you want to investigate more, I found a good [post](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/the-best-10-wordpress-translation-plugins-for-going-multilingual) comparing different wordpress translation plugins both free and premium.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey Diego, thanks for this I'll check out WPML. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad it helped! if it was useful please mark this as correct.